# overflow-scrolling : touch bind scroll position for cordova ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, scroll, touch

When the scroll feature is assigned to an element with CSS;

For example:

```
#page{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

<div id="page"></div>
```

How to bind with a sliding movement of these elements JavaScript ??

I've tried something like this but not working !!!

```
$('#page').on('scroll',function(e){
 var scrollPosition = e.target.scrollTop;
console.log(scrollPosition);
});
```

This code on iOS devices triggered only finished the scroll position and updates.
I would like to bind all the scrolls as momentary movements of the diver with a scroll feature.

Scroll movement does not return a value until it is completed we make a quick stop scrolling the screen. Scroll motion (momentum scroll) finished upgrader.
**I try to do to prevent it and how I can do this momentum scroll to bind???**

This example (http://adliy.com/scroll) running iOS safari but this example does not work in WebView as we receive a cordovan project's my problem with it

Comment: i think it has to be `$(e.target).scrollTop();`

Comment: The problem is not the code work. Problems only moments scroll continuously on the move can not bind the return value is finished.  Thank you. @dvenkatsagar